# Converting a Multipicklist to a Text through Formula/Trigger

Tags: trigger, formula, picklist

Is there a way to convert the multipicklist to a text?

Since I have hundreds near to thousand of picklist I want to convert it  text and the only way I think is a trigger and copy that text to one of the fields afterwards.

For example, I have chosen `LA,CA,PA,HI,NV,RA,SA,QE,SC,TA,SA` and I want to Add those multipicklist into field called Opportunity Name  having the name CountryOpp so the Result would be Opporunity Name: `CountryOpp-LA-CA-PA-HI-NV-RA-SA-QE-SC-TA-SA`

Answer (score 3):

Certainly via trigger, you could just replace the multi-select delimiter (`;`) with any character you want (including dashes) and prefix it, suffix it, or manipulate in any other which way:

```
trigger MyObject on MyObject__c (before insert, before update)
{
    for (MyObject__c record : trigger.new)
    {
        String multiSelect = record.Multi_Select__c;
        if (multiSelect != null)
        {
            record.Name = 'SomePrefix' + multiSelect.replace(';', '-')
        }
    }
}
```

A couple considerations:

- You will likely run into length issues on the `Name` field. It would be a better idea to put this data into a longer field or consider truncation schemes.
- You should move this code out into an `Apex Class`, the above code is only meant to demonstrate the idea. If you move it to a [Service Layer](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_patterns_sl), for example, you could call the same code from a batch.